# Android Kotlin MediaCodec failed on configure

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediacodec

I'll try to start the video encoder, but my code constantly fails to configure.

I found this code from chat GPT and did not find the solution in Google.

```
val videoEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC)
val videoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(
    MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC,
    previewView.width,
    previewView.height
)
videoEncoder.configure(
    videoFormat,
    null,
    null,
    MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE
)
videoEncoder.start()
```

here is the error message

```
Codec reported err 0xffffffea/BAD_VALUE, actionCode 0, while in state 3/CONFIGURING
```

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a video encoder, the supplied `MediaFormat` object must include certain required parameters (e.g. color format, frame rate, I-frame interval, bitrate) as key-value pairs.

The format created by the call `MediaFormat.createVideoFormat()` contains MIME type, width and height. It's up to you to provide the rest of them.

For example:

```
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30)
```

You can find the complete list in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat).

Also, it is worth reading the `MediaCodec` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec).

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't find the answer yet, 0xffffffea/BAD_VALUE means that one of config params that you set don't supported by encoder.
For example you provide previewView.width & previewView.height But for h264 encoder supported can be different for different devices.

You will need to check:

```
val videoCapabilities = videoEncoder.codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType("video/avc").videoCapabilities
if (!videoCapabilities.supportedWidths.contains(width) || !videoCapabilities.supportedHeights.contains(height)) {
   Logger.d(TAG, "Encoder can't deal with $height x $width") 
   // todo maybe you want to do here:
   width = videoCapabilities.supportedWidths.clamp(width)
   height = videoCapabilities.supportedHeights.clamp(height)
}
```

Also you have params like `videoCapabilities.supportedFrameRates` and `videoCapabilities.bitrateRange`

Good luck.